# How to SELECT * into a SQL table incremntally by date?

Tags: sql-server, backup, increment, sql-job

I have a SQL Server table called "tblProducts".

Sometimes I backup this table by making a copy of it with this simple query:

```
SELECT *
INTO [test01].[dbo].[tblProducts_20141206]
FROM [test01].[dbo].[tblProducts]
```

Every time when making a backup, the date is included in the table name.

I would like to create a SQL Job that runs this kind of query once every week.

Is it possible to maybe in a stored procedure or declaring a variable to achieve this that allows the backed-up table name to be named like [tblProducts_todaysDate]?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append SQL table name with today's date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592508/append-sql-table-name-with-todays-date)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a SP, you can do something like:

```
 CREATE PROC sp_createATable
 @name        VARCHAR(20) AS
 CREATE TABLE @name
 ...
 do your insert
```

Or, if you want to, w/o SP:

```
 DECLARE @name varchar(20)
 SET @name = 'tblName' + SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) AS [YYYYMMDD]
 CREATE TABLE @name
 ...
 do your insert
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `Dynamic SQL` to create the tables names appended with date.

```
CREATE PROC usp_createtable( @tablename VARCHAR(20), 
                 @Dbname    VARCHAR(20), 
                 @SchemaName VARCHAR(20)) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) 
    SET @sql =' SELECT * INTO '+@Dbname+'.'+@SchemaName+'.'+@tablename+'CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) FROM '+@Dbname+'.'+@SchemaName+'.'+@tablename'' 
    EXEC sp_executesql 
      @sql 
  END
```